# How to get text of specific element - Xamarin UI Test

Tags: c#, android, xamarin, uitest, xamarin.uitest

I have:

> [TextView] id: "MonthValue" text: "11"

I want to get text as String of id **MonthValue**

Comment: I need: "11" as String

Answer (score 5):

Just use the query's `Text` property:

`app.Query(c => c.Id("MonthValue").Text`

Reference: https://developer.xamarin.com/api/property/Xamarin.UITest.Queries.AppResult.Text/

Answer (score 3):

Want to update Jim's answer. app.Query return an array, so we can not use 
`app.Query(c => c.Id("MonthValue")).Text` as itself. We should use `app.Query(c => c.Id("MonthValue"))[0].Text` for example

Answer (score 1):

`app.Query(c => c.Id("MonthValue").Text("11"))` should do it

Comment: Yes, but I have to get this value, because I can change this value by +/- .
sth what should work like:
String x = app.Query(c => c.Id("MonthValue").getText())

Comment: AppResult has a Text property, so try app.Query(c => c.Id("MonthValue")).Text.   https://developer.xamarin.com/api/property/Xamarin.UITest.Queries.AppResult.Text/

Answer (score 1):

I was also stuck in the same problem, though I got the solution via debug through `Repl()` command.
Try to use with index position like this:

```
app.Query(c=>c.Id("NoResourceEntry-8"))[0].Text
```

similarly you can use class for same:

```
app.Query(c=>c.Class("LabelRenderer"))[0].Text
```

Query for `Class("LabelRenderer")` gave 2 results.
So in the above example, you can see it gave you 2 results but you have to use index for a particular result.